# PC goes to boot menu after waking up from sleep

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, suspend, wakeup

I've been using xubuntu 16.04 since it came out. A couple of month ago I decided to install it on my laptop along with windows 10. The problem I faces has been around since the beginning of dual OS. Every time I put the computer to suspend and then decide to wake it up it goes automatically to boot menu (grub). when I wake the pc up I have to use the power button because it won't answer to keyboard and the mouse which I think is very strange. I suspect that it is something wrong the `grub`. I remember once I tried to use "`sudo update-grub`" and nothing happened. here is some specifications if needed:

Here is the [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gySMTPRYbF/)

**my PC is a laptop hp probook 650 with onboard graphics**

/etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Partitions:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x824b708d

Device         Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p2        1026048 305438974 304412927 145,2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p3      305440768 307199999   1759232   859M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/nvme0n1p4      307202046 471263231 164061186  78,2G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      307202048 463450111 156248064  74,5G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p6      463452160 471263231   7811072   3,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Linux peyam 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here are some other specification:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a804
```

More on computer hardware : [sudo lshw](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pJTQ8cSfGW/)

The computer I use is a *Hp probook 650 G3.*

What do I do to avoid getting Grub menu every time pc wakes up from suspend

Comment: no! it is not the same. The graphics for instance in my case is onboard.

Comment: Please edit your question stating how you tried answers in duplicate and how they didn't work so we can  retract close voting. Then post comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I'm questioning whether your system is actually suspending.  Please [edit] your question to provide the output of  `cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log`  thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Yes. I will as soon Im behind pc

Comment: I find the answer. It is a known bug on NMVe ssd drivers. I found an answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd .  Gonna test and come back