# Root file system sometimes mounted read-only after resume from suspend on Dell laptop with 18.04 Bionic

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, root, read-only, resume

My freshly installed Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop has a weird problem. After resuming from suspend mode, sometimes the root file system is mounted read-only. This happens more often (but not always) when I plug in or unplug the power supply when the system is suspended.

The root file system is mounted with the following options:

```
rw,relatime,**errors=remount-ro**,data=ordered.
```

The above is the line in the output of the `mount` command pertaining to the root file system. The `rw` at the start of this line changes to `ro` once the problem occurs.

I'm fairly sure that the `errors=remount-ro` parameter is relevant here, but I'm not in favor of simply removing it and thereby suppress the symptoms without addressing whatever the cause of the problem is.

I am not sure how to narrow down the possible causes of this strange behavior. There's nothing in `/var/log/*` because that's on the read-only file system (or rather on the root fs which has gone `ro` when the problem occurs) which makes it impossible to log any relevant output.

*Smartctl* gives the harddisk a clean bill of health. Which stands to reason, because this is a brand new laptop. The output of `upower --monitor` shows nothing out of the ordinary when I unplug and replug the power supply.

What can I do to find out what's going on here?

Comment: Did you ever use Ubuntu 16.04 without this error? I've read a lot of suspend/resume problems with 18.04 in general.

Comment: Do you have an NVMe SSD? If so see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd

Comment: My previous HP-550 laptop with 12.04 on it (yes, ancient!) died and was replaced with the new Dell Inspiron 15 on which I installed 18.04. Suspend works, hibernation does't. Smartctl reports the device model as ST1000LM035-1RK172 which I take to be a Seagate harddisk. It's definitely not an SSD.