# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity desktop freeze when waking from suspend

Tags: unity, suspend, freeze

Ubuntu 16.04 Unity freezes when waking from suspend. This system runs on my desktop with 8 GB RAM, a 120 GB SSD (46% full), Pentium (R) Dual Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00 GHz with on board graphics.

Previously, I was able to reboot via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd> or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>F1</kbd> then ps -ef, sudo reboot but now the only thing that works is a force reboot via power off.

Any advice will be welcomed.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd

Comment: I have subsequently cleaned up many files by following and using the Synaptic Package Manager "mark upgrades", "missing recommends"  and "fix broken packages" facilities.  This appears to have solved the problem. Wake from suspend is now quick and effective.