# Alienware R5 17 laptop crashes on suspend

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, suspend

This occurs with both the 4.15 stock Ubuntu kernel and the 4.18.5 kernel I updated to in order to get the wifi interface to work. (Updated using uuku)

Things I have tried:

- Installing latest nvidia drivers with ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

  - Doing this blacklists the nouveau driver which is the source of many posts on the topic.
  - Disabling the nvidia-fallback.service causes the system to black screen on login so I re-enabled that service.

I can't find anything suspicious looking in any of the logs.

[Update 09/19/2018: I ran through the instructions in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend and interestingly the forced suspend command it contains does *NOT* trigger the crashing behavior! I can resume just fine when I do that - although I had to substitute systemctl suspend for the pm_suspend command since that's no longer available in 18.04 I think? Does closing the lid trigger a different suspend mechanism than systemctl suspend?]

Comment: Seems to me I had that problem too when testing `18.04`. With `16.04.5` suspend with nVidia drivers `384.130` works fine. Do  you have an NVMe M.2 SSD Gen 3.0x4 installed? If so see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd/981658#981658

Comment: I *do* have that brand of SSD! Thanks so much for the link! Make this an answer so I can mark it correct if it works and get you the points :)

Answer (score 1):

In rare cases when resuming after suspend NVMe M.2 SSD's are not powered up again if they are Gen 3.0 x 4 bus lanes. Although this was promised to be fixed in an older kernel version it has not appeared yet: [Cannot suspend with NVMe M.2 SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd/981658#981658)

If you have such an SSD try the following:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo` powers and find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet kaslr acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=off nloglevel=3 udev.log-priority=3"
```

Your options will be different but add the option `acpihp.disable=1` between the double quotes.

Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`.

Reboot and then suspend and resume will work.

Comment: Hrrm. Thanks I haven't had luck with this yet.

Comment: I edited my /etc/default/grub like so:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpiphp.disable=1 splash"

Comment: It's not the problem but it's tradition to put new variables after `quiet splash` so it would look like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiphp.disable=1"`. As I mentioned previously I had problems suspending in `18.04` which is one of the reasons I'm using `16.04` instead. It could very well be you have another problems besides/instead of the NVMe SSD.

Comment: @ChristopherPatti Sorry just noticed the command `sudo update-grub` was missing. I added it to the answer.