# Ubuntu 20.10 NVME I/O timeout after suspend exit

Tags: boot, suspend, power-management, 20.10, nvme

I set up dual-booted Ubuntu 20.10 for Asus ZenBook UX393EA. Each time when resuming from suspend, the screen freezes in black for tens of seconds, and after logged in, the OS is extremely laggy for another tens of seconds.

I try to look up in the system logs, and I find `PM: suspend exit` logs are always followed by several `nvme nvme0: I/O 0 QID 2 timeout, aborting` and `nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0` logs, while in ubuntu 20.04 there are no such nvme timeout logs (and therefore no freeze and lag). So I guess it's related to the issue. I searched around and finally found solution in this post [Cannot suspend with NVMe M.2 SSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/981657/1156482). I added `pcie_aspm=off` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, then the nvme timeout logs never appears and the issue concerning suspend is gone.

My questions are: Does this solution really fit the issue? What could be the root cause? How is pcie_aspm related to nvme timeout after suspend exit? Would there be any harm by turning aspm off?

system logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RftJhHDprK/

Comment: Did you ever find the problem? I seem to be having the same problem.

Comment: @Telegonicaxx it has been working all fine in my laptop after I added `pcie_aspm=off` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. For your infomation, [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/226319/what-does-pcie-aspm-do) explains what `pcie_aspm` does.

Comment: Much obliged @PocupineAndrew. Thank for leading me in the right direction.