# My Pc wont recover fron suspend

Tags: 16.04

I Have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my PC . My PC Can't recover from suspend or hibernate. my swap partition is 8GB. When i press suspend, my PC go suspend but when i want to recover, a black screen will be show.

Comment: If you have an NVMe M.2 SSD check this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/851126/16-04-suspend-resume-failure-with-nvme-disk